# What does <> mean?

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen this before in SQL and VB, I am now reverse engineering an Excel speadsheet and have come across the following formula:

```
=IF(D23<>0,"Insufficent",0)
```

I am converting it to ActionScript:

```
var result:String = [condition] ? 0 : "Insufficient";
```

but I am unsure of what D23 <> 0 means, is it simply "not equal"?

Comment: I think the <> inequality operator actually originates from the BASIC language.

Comment: I instinctively read it as "different from". "!=" hits me milliseconds after.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, it means "not equal", either less than or greater than.
e.g

```
If x <> y Then
```

can be read as

if *x is less than y* **or** x *is greater than y* then

The logical outcome being "If x is anything **except** equal to y"

Comment: okay!! First I was confused with the question! I knew about "not equalto" but was wondering if there is anything else :)

Comment: This made me think, what's the oprator for "equal"? Is it just "="?

Comment: @Shayan: In vba, yes "=" means "equal" for simple types `if i = 1 then`. For objects you need is `if objRefA is objRefB then`. [See this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254401/vba-how-to-test-for-object-equality-whether-two-variables-reference-the-same-o/11254505)

Answer (score 10):

Yes in SQl <> is the same as != which is not equal.....excepts for NULLS of course, in that case you need to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 7):

It means not equal to.  The same as != seen in C style languages, as well as actionscript.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's "not equal".

Answer (score 4):

"Does not equal"

Comment: Valid correction: Is* - "Is" instead of "Does"