# Comparing two Sheet objects (not contents)

Tags: vba

In the context of an error handling code, I would like to verify if the user has given to the current sheet the same name of another one into the same workbook (action forbidden, of course). So the way I intuitively tried to verify this was simply to loop through all the sheets and comparing the names:

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
        'error handling here
    End If
Next sh
```

However, this is a huge logic fall in the case when:

1) The user is editing, let's say, the sheet number 3; 
2) The sheet with the same name is at the position number 5;

In that case, the condition `sh.Name = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name` would be met for sure because the sheet is compared to itself.

So, I wonder: **how to understand if `sh` is not `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`**?

I had thought the task it could have simply been solved with a simple object comparison:

```
If (sh Is Not ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet) And (sh.Name = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Then
```

but this raises a compile error, namely *Object does not support this property or method*. Could anyone please help me finding the lack of logic in my code's structure?

**OTHER INFORMATION**

I have tried to manage the case through the `Err.Description` and the `Err.Number`, but the first is OS-language dependent and the second is the same for other types of error I need to handle differently.

Moreover, the sheets (names and contents) are contained into a `.xlam` add-in so the user can change the contents through custom user-forms but not through the Excel Application.

More in general, let's say that I would like to know how can I perform the comparison, even if a work-around in this specific case is possible, in order to use this method for future developments I already plan to do and that cannot be managed through the default VBA error handler.

Comment: Is the user giving "the same name to another sheet" in VBA code or through manual input?  Because manual input gives you an error: _"That sheet name is already in use.  Enter a sheet name that is not in use by another sheet."_

Comment: @Christmas007, The name is input through a textbox on a UserForm, and updates itself into the `TextBox_Change` event. I have already tried managing through the `Err.Description` but the message is raised into the OS language and this would cause cross-languages issues. Tried also through the error-code, but it's the same of other cases that must be managed differently. Moreover, I'd just like to know how to properly compare the two objects because I will need it furtherly when no specific error is raised.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky please read my above comment for better understanding of the context. The sheets are contained into an Add-In so the user changes names and contents of the sheet through user-forms, while never seeing the sheet on the desktop. That's (unfortunately) why I need to build a custom error handler :(

Comment: Does the userform change the name of the Active (at that very moment) sheet?

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, yes, exactly. It starts with an `On Error GoTo Handler` and then changes the name, so if we enter the handler is because an error occurred. Even in this case, as I wrote to RubberDuck, I know I might just perform the check first and change  the name then, but I'd like to avoid work-arounds and rather know if there's a direct way to perform an object instance comparison.

Comment: Just realized that there's a bug in your logic:
 
"The user is editing, let's say, the sheet number 3; 2) ***The sheet with the same name** is at the position number 5*"
 
It's impossible to create two or more sheets with the same name.

Comment: @MaciejLos, you're perfectly right, I have just realized this. Well, I'd say that I leave this question just for the precious content you and two other users have added to it, but I agree on the fact that otherwise it wouldn't have reason to exist!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, i didn't say: delete this question ;) Cheers, Maciej.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the index of the worksheet along with the name.
Only error (or whatever) if the name matches, but the index doesn't.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim wsToCheck As Worksheet
    For Each wsToCheck In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = wsToCheck.Name And ws.Index <> wsToCheck.Index Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course, you could always just [test for object equality using the `Is` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254505/3198973) too, or inequality in your specific case.

```
Public Sub test2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim wsToCheck As Worksheet
    For Each wsToCheck In wb.Worksheets
        If Not ws Is wsToCheck Then
            'do something
            Debug.Print ws.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Very bright move, cannot deny an upvote. However, I'd still like to know if it's possible to perform an instance comparison. What I mean is that `sh` and `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` might turn to be the same object instance. I will accept this answer lately if we don't discover how to perform the comparison I was asking for. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Well, it turned it was just a stupid syntax error, I was writing `sh Is Not` instead of `Not sh Is`. I have suggested this edit and accepted your answer as it fully answers my question!

Comment: I am upvoting your answer for the second (excellent) answer. However the first part might fail in case we have two identical workbooks and the queried worksheets are respective sheets from those two workbooks (they'll have the same name and index, **but** different workbooks behind).

Answer (score 4):

You've got an incorrect syntax with "Not"; it should be this:

```
If (Not sh Is ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet) And (sh.Name = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Then
```

Comment: Again, I am a few seconds late :(

Comment: Thank you Gene, just realized it! For sake of fairness I keep on accepting RubberDuck's answer, but thanks a lot for your help, +1 !!!

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky it earned an upvote from me, but I find it nice to upvote questions that you find are worth the time to answer. I mean, if it's worth answering, isn't it worth the upvote?

Comment: @RubberDuck, completely agree, this is our way of rewarding the time a user has kindly spent for us ;)

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, i'd like to call you: Hawk eye!

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason to loop through the collection of sheets. Use this:

```
Function IsWshExists(ByVal wbk As Workbook, ByVal wshName As String) As Boolean
Dim wsh As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set wsh = wbk.Worksheets(wshName)

IsWshExists = (Err.Number = 0)

Set wsh = Nothing
End Function
```

Usage:

```
If Not IsWshExists(ThisWorkbook, "Sheet2") Then 
    'you can add worksheet ;)
    'your logic here
End If
```

Comment: It works, but relying on an error handler and resuming next is pretty dang hacky.

Comment: Mmm, this lacks a bit actually. If I pass an empty string as name, the function will tell me the worksheet exists while this is not true, won't it?

Comment: Ha, ha, ha! @RubberDuck, using "Resume Next" isn't "dang hacky" (whatever it means), but pretty good programming practice. There is only one condition: the programmer must be consious of usage such of trick.

Comment: If you are going to write `On Error Resume Next` you better turn it off when you are done with that one error handling instance... `On Error GoTo 0`...

Comment: The general error handling approach Maceej Los is okay - but you should test for `If Not wsh is Nothing` etc, Matteo NNZ raises a fair point as the way you have run this

Comment: No, @Chrismas007, because the code does not need to fired again in case of error.

Comment: When put into a larger sub, you need to turn error checking back on.

Comment: @Chrismas007 he actually doesn't need to in this case, but yes. What you are saying is best practice in general.

Comment: @brettdj, there is no reason to check if wsh is nothing. Function will return false if worksheet does not exists (even if empty string has been passed).

Comment: @MaciejLos, I really appreciate your time and yours is actually a cool approach for many problems. What I mean is just that, in my context, I need to know if another sheet with the same name exists. Your function would work perfectly fine in that case, but it would raise the same result (i.e. Existing) even if I pass an invalid name such as an empty string or a string containing a special character like *, : etc. You see my point? :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, not sure... If i understand you well, you want to check if worksheet exists (by its name) and nothing else. Probably, you need to check if workseet with given name exists, before you change its name. Is there anything what i missed?