# Using the "Is" operator vs. comparing ObjPtr values

Tags: vba

In VBA, is comparing two objects with the `Is` operator the same as comparing their `ObjPtr` values?

That is, is this

```
obj1 Is obj2
```

... the same as this?

```
ObjPtr(obj1) = ObjPtr(obj2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254401/vba-how-to-test-for-object-equality-whether-two-variables-reference-the-same-o/11254505

Comment: Yes they should be the same. Did you encounter cases where they're not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: how to test for object equality (whether two variables reference the same object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254401/vba-how-to-test-for-object-equality-whether-two-variables-reference-the-same-o)