# VBA Compare 2 XML nodes to see if they are the same node

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ms-word

In VBA (with reference to MSXML2.DOMDocument60) I have two nodes:

```
Dim nodeFoo As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim nodeBar As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
```

These nodes are assigned values, for what its worth nodeFoo is assigned via an xPath expression whereas nodeBar is assigned by looping through a set of nodes.

The challenge is to determine if:  `nodeBar = nodeFoo` *(i.e. if it is the same actual node)*.

Searching google suggested it is possible using [isSameNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_issamenode.asp) but I'm unable to find an equivalent in MSXML2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254401/vba-how-to-test-for-object-equality-whether-two-variables-reference-the-same-o

Comment: Oh... thanks - I'll have a quick test

Comment: Works, I think the question is fair and adds value - if you care to answer it I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd use `Is` to determine whether two object variables point to the same object.

E.g. see [VBA: how to test for object equality (whether two variables reference the same object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254401/vba-how-to-test-for-object-equality-whether-two-variables-reference-the-same-o)

Example:

```
For Each nodeFoo In allNodes
If nodeFoo Is nodeBar Then 
    ' do something
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I was going insane looking for something similar to isSameNode