# VBA function for Controls in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, function, userform

I'm very new to VBA so I apologise if the question seems silly: I have set up a UserForm with some controls in it, and created a function called `ResetMyField` as per below:

```
Function ResetMyField(MyField As Object)
    If MyField = ProjectReference Then
        'do something different and then
    End If
    MyField.Value = ""
End Function
```

When I call this function using `ResetMyField(ProjectReference)` VBA comes out with a 424 error (Object Required). Should I be declaring `MyField` as a different type of variable in the function?

Both the function and the point at which I call it are inside the Userform module.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ProjectReference is the name of one of my Comboboxes on the Userform - sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Which line throws that error? Any why do you use a `function` if you don't return something you can use a procedure (`Sub`). Can you [edit] your question and add the code how exactly you call `ResetMyField`? If you are testing 2 objects for equality I recommend to test their name for equality `MyField.Name = ProjectReference.Name`

Answer (score 2):

`ResetMyField(ProjectReference)`, [with the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683), tries to pass the [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) of the `ProjectReference` combobox into `ResetMyField`. The default property of a combobox is `Value`, and that is not an `Object`, and `ResetMyField` expects an `Object`, hence the error ("Object Required").

[Remove the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331147/11683):

```
ResetMyField ProjectReference
```

Also note that `If MyField = ProjectReference Then`, again, tries to compare default properties of `MyField` and `ProjectReference`, which in case of comboboxes will mean `If MyField.Value = ProjectReference.Value Then`.
If you want to know if `MyField` [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254505/11683) `ProjectReference`, then it's

```
If MyField Is ProjectReference Then
```