# What does the "<>" operator mean?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is some code that I got from another website, but I am not able to understand what the `<>` sign does.  Can someone please explain it?

```
   Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

   With FldrPicker
       .Title = "Select folder:"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
       myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With
```

Comment: it checks if `FldrPicker.Show` does Not = -1

Comment: <> means "not equal to"

Comment: big thanks @ShaiRado and haseena !

Comment: Have you even googled this before posting? Search terms as basic as `excel vba <>` would instantly get you the correct answer.

Comment: i googled it before already but i can't understand it or maybe i just dont go for a deep search for this. sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [inequality operator](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Operators-And-Functions.html), ≠.

Comment: Why to answer this question instead of closing and mark as duplicated [of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532435/what-does-mean?rq=1) ?

Comment: @Sgdva I've cast a vote to close this question, and singled the duplicate.

Comment: @farahxx If I have answered your question, please mark my question as answered.