# Spreadsheets get unique names but ignore blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I would like to use spreadsheets to get all unique names from Column A in a table but in the same time I would like blank cells to be ignored. So far I've got this formula that returns all of the unique names from column A but I don't know how to go about ignoring blank cells and not repeating values that have once been added previously.

[Here](http://prntscr.com/gyhr70) is how my document looks so far. As you can see everything stops after Megan because there is a blank cell.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$90, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($I$10:I10, $A$2:$A$90), 0)), "")`

Searched long and wide but came up with nothing, if anyone has any idea how one could do that I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`=unique(A2:A)` should work

`=unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))` to also ignore blanks

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply but using your formula returns duplicate values as you can see here http://prntscr.com/gyhxmh

Comment: It works, my bad when trying to use it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Max Makhrov I used this method to remove a string that was my headers as well as ignore white space! I was curious if there was a name for the `<>` notation or if you could provide any further documentation.

Comment: @ConstantFun, I cannot find the documentation for `<>`. This is known from Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532435/what-does-mean

Comment: unique is an excel beta function, what about any other formula which will with Excel 2019 or older stable version?

Comment: NOT(ISBLANK(...)) also availabe (more readable)

eg. FILTER(A2:B10, NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A10)))

Comment: `=unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))` removes any empty/blank row. `=unique(A2:A)` does NOT. I tested four values (strings and numbers separately) where there was one duplicate value and used the `ROWS` function to display the number of rows of data returned. `=rows(unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")))` returned a value of 3 (no empty row) whereas `=rows(unique(A2:A))` returns a value of 4 (i.e. it includes the empty row).

Answer (score 25):

### Yet another hack

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A))
```

Technically, this **does not remove** the blank result. But nonetheless puts it at the end of the list. You'll also benefit from the sort if you need it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use query:

```
=unique(query(A2:A,"select A where A<>''"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$90, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($I$10:I10, $A$2:$A$90)+($A$2:$A$90=""), ), 0)), "")
```

should work